# C# Set variable using string that has variable name inside

Tags: c#, xml, system.reflection

*Switched over to serailization.

Summary: I have all the variables pre-defined as null / 0. I want to set them using data from and XML document. The document contains the exact same names as the variables. I don't want to use a bunch of else ifs so I'm trying to do it based on the names I pull from the XML document.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public class ShipAttributes
{
    // Model Information
    string name;
    string modelName;
    string firingPosition;
    string cameraPosition;
    string cargoPosition;
    Vector3 cameraDistance;

    // Rotation
    float yawSpeed;
    float pitchSpeed;
    float rollSpeed;

    // Speed
    float maxSpeed;
    float cruiseSpeed;
    float drag;
    float maxAcceleration;
    float maxDeceleration;

    // Physics Properties
    float mass;

    // Collection Capacity
    float cargoSpace;

    // Combat [Defense]
    float structureHealth;
    float armorHealth;
    float shieldHealth;
    float shieldRadius;

    // Combat [Assault]
    float missileRechargeTime;
    float fireRate; 

    // Currency Related
    float cost;
    float repairMultiplier;

void PopulateShipList()
{
    if (shipList != null)
        return;

    string filepath = Application.dataPath + "/Resources/shipsdata.xml";

    XmlRootAttribute xml_Root = new XmlRootAttribute();
    xml_Root.ElementName = "SHIPS";
    xml_Root.IsNullable = true;
    //using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) 
    //{
        StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(filepath);
        stringReader.Read();
        XmlReader xRdr = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
        XmlSerializer xml_s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ShipAttributes>), xml_Root);
        shipList= (List<ShipAttributes>)xml_s.Deserialize(xRdr);
    //}
}
public ShipAttributes LoadShip(string inName)
{
    PopulateShipList();
    foreach (ShipAttributes att in shipList)
    {
        if (att.name == inName)
        {
            att.shipList = shipList;
            return att;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

*Note Variables in the XML files have the exact same Format and Name as the variables in the class. maxSpeed in Class is maxSpeed in XML file.

My XML looks like this --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8 without BOM" ?>

     <SHIPS>
        <SHIP>
            <name>Default</name>
            <id>0</id>
            <modelName>Feisar_Ship</modelName>
            <firingPosition>null</firingPosition>
            <cameraPosition>null</cameraPosition>
            <cargoPosition>null</cargoPosition>
            <cameraDistance>null</cameraDistance>
            <yawSpeed>2000.0</yawSpeed>
            <pitchSpeed>3000.0</pitchSpeed>
            <rollSpeed>10000.15</rollSpeed>
            <maxSpeed>200000.0</maxSpeed>
            <cruiseSpeed>100000.0</cruiseSpeed>
            <drag>0.0</drag>
            <maxAcceleration>null</maxAcceleration>
            <maxDeceleration>null</maxDeceleration>
            <mass>5000.0</mass>
            <cargoSpace>150.0</cargoSpace>
            <structureHealth>100.0</structureHealth>
            <armorHealth>25.0</armorHealth>
            <shieldHealth>25.0</shieldHealth>
            <shieldRadius>30.0</shieldRadius>
            <missileRechargeTime>2.0</missileRechargeTime>
            <fireRate>0.5f</fireRate>
            <cost>0</cost>
            <repairMultiplier>1.0</repairMultiplier>
        </SHIP>   
     </SHIPS
```

>

Yes Yes I know... Feisar! Just place holders for now from turbosquid.

Comment: I don't understand your 3rd and 4th steps...? Are these variables of yours part of a class? And, could that class just be deserialised from the XML document directly? Lastly: not actually sure what you're asking :)

Comment: Sample of your class would be useful (assuming "variable" means property/field of a class, not a local variable of some method).

Comment: Updated with Code from what I'm doing. I'm trying to set the variables without saying speed = attribute.innertext.

I want to say [Psuedo] attribute.name.thisIsNowTheVariable = attribute.innerText;

Attribute being an XML node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class to hold the values you are reading in and use XML Serialization.

[Microsoft Tutorial](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813)

[Tech Pro Tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)

[MSDN: XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

**EDIT :**

If the XML is exactly the same as the class code you posted, the following should allow you to get a class of `ShipAttributes`:

```
ShipAttributes attributes = null;
string filepath = "/path/to/xml";

using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    var xml_s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ShipAttributes));

    attributes = (ShipAttributes)xml_s.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

**Edit 2 : Multiple Ships**

In your comment, you said that the file contains multiple `ShipAttribute` descriptions.  The way to handle that is the same as above, but deserialize the file into the type `List<ShipAttribute>` as follows:

```
List<ShipAttributes> ships = null;
string filepath = "/path/to/xml";

using (var stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
    var xml_s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ShipAttributes>));

    ships= (List<ShipAttributes>)xml_s.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Once you've done that, you have all of the ships in memory and can pick the one out of the list you need using Linq etc.

Comment: I did come across this, haven't tried serializing yet. That'll be new to me. Will work it out tomorrow if the other way doesn't work.

Comment: Edit: 

Interesting, so if I put the order of the variables in the XML in the same order they are in within the class, this would set all the attributes in the class as it was read in?

Comment: Errr, The only problem with this is, I'll be storing multiple ships in the XML so I have to be able to skip through them until I find which ship I  need. The deserialization doesn't seem to allow for this type of work.

Comment: The order of the variables doesn't matter...the XmlSerializer is smart enough to figure out where they go based on name.  See my edit for multiple ships

Comment: I guess I could set the name on creation of the class. Then have the serializer compare the name and then jump down into that ship node. But I almost have it working this way. I do want to give the serializer a shot as an alternative later but I'm sooooo close.

Comment: With that being the case, this is probably a much better way ahaha. How would I be able to know to go down that node?

Comment: OH, gotcha. But if I'm trying to run this on iOS memory might be a concern with using lists.

Comment: I had this sudden urge to say Danke Schoen but I was like naaah he probably doesn't know german. Then I clicked your profile to see if I could thank you in a message and you were in Germany so Danke Schoen.

Comment: Unless you have *thousands* of ships, memory shouldn't be a problem.  It will also save you quite a bit of processing by only loading the data once instead of every time you want to access a different ship.

Comment: I've got it to the point where it's telling me Text node cannot appear in this state. I tried what they had on the Unity page but to no avail. S

Comment: It looks like you've got one element too many in your XML.  You want to have one element that contains all of your ships: <ArrayOfShip><Ship>...</Ship><Ship>...</Ship></ArrayOfShip>

Comment: I had actually done that last night before I logged off, It didn't work. I tried the tricks mentioned here http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/10904/xmlexception-text-node-canot-appear-in-this-state.html as I am using Unity. They don't seem to work.

Also I updated my Original Code to reflect where I am at now.

Answer (score 0):

**ASSUMING YOU XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Variables>      
    <VariableName1>1</VariableName1>
    <VariableName2>test</VariableName2>
    <VariableName3>test2</VariableName3>    
</Variables>



var data = XDocument.Load("YourXML.xml");
var xmldata = from x in data.Descendants("Variables")                        
                        select x;

notes.Select(_BuildPropertyFromElement);



private Yourclassname _BuildNoteFromElement(XElement element)
    {
      var type = typeof(**Yourclassname**);
      var Details = new Yourclassname();

      foreach (var propInfo in type.GetProperties())
      {
         var rawValue = element.Element(propInfo.Name).Value;
         var convertedValue = propInfo.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) ?         (object)Convert.ToDateTime(rawValue) : rawValue;
            propInfo.SetValue(Details , convertedValue, null);
                }

                return Details ;
            }
```

**YOURCLASSNAME is the name of the class which would have all the properties you want to set to**

Comment: The right way would be serializing it but i have posted in a way which you are trying

Comment: I'll give this a look see when my brain isn't falling asleep. I'll get back to you tomorrow on this.